# Output text from template txt file with dynamic values

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

I have a template txt file (example):

> test_asd = value
>   this is the end of the file

From which I need to create other text files with different values in the place of `value`

I'm writing a program to use this in `C#` (using a child process `cmd.exe` and commands)

I have tried setting an environment variable but the output is not different from the original template file.

test.txt:

> test_asd = %VALUE%
>   this is the end of the file

C#:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("VALUE", "test");

Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo = psi;

p.Start();

p.StandardInput.WriteLine("type test.txt");
p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

p.WaitForExit();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);

Console.ReadLine(); // wait for 'Enter' to exit
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, here is the command:

```
type test.txt | sed.exe -e "s/\${value}/test/"
```

using [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

thanks to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415677/how-to-replace-placeholders-in-a-text-file)