# Read template file and replace variable using Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to read a template file then replace a variable within this file using the Bash shell as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/415698/889099).

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
website_name=new_website_name
while read line 
do
    eval echo "$line"
done < "/etc/apache2/extra/vhost-template.txt"
```

This works with a test template file (vhost-template.txt) with this content:

```
Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/${website_name}"
```

the placeholder is replaced and I get the correct output:

```
Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/new_website_name"
```

However my real template file contains some invalid characters such as the < and > characters:
This is my full template file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemailaddress@xyz.com
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/${website_name}/web/"
    ServerName dev.${website_root_dir}.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/${website_name}-dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/${website_name}-dev-access_log" common

    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/${website_name}">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is causing the following errors:

```
./virtualsetup.sh: eval: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

./virtualsetup.sh: eval: line 5: `echo <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/${website_name}">'
```

I have tried escaping the < and > characters using the back slash or changing them to

```
'&lt;' or '&gt;'
```

e.g.

```
\<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/${website_name}"\>
```

but this gives the same error
and

```
&lt;Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/${website_name}"&gt;
```

gives this error:

gt: command not found

I have also tried wrapping the entire template file in double quotes, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: what is in `"/Library/WebServer/Documents/${website_name}"`? Are they `var=value` pairs? Why would you seek to `eval` them instead of `source` them if they are?

Comment: I should probably have explained a bit more what I am trying to do. I am trying to automatically create a virtual host in apache by reading in a standard virtual host from a template file then replacing certain elements with user input. I'll edit my question above with my complete template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place single quotes (not double) around `$line`:

```
eval echo '$line'
```

Edit:  I misunderstood the question previously.  The solution does not require an `eval`, but can be done using a simple substitution:

```
line=${line/\${website_name\}/$website_name}
echo $line
```

Comment: Hi @cdarke, this works for me to a point. If I use the single quotes it outputs the template file without any errors however the placeholder in the template file is not replaced with the variable (new_website_name). E.g. I now get this returned: <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/${website_name}" /> –

Comment: I couldn't find any info on this, but I couldn't get it to work if `line` contains a closing curly brace, for example if `line` is just `}`