# Regex to identify reference to environment variables in bash

Tags: regex, bash, variables, eval, substitution

We know that 'eval' can do evil things: Like execute code.
I need a way in BASH to be able to identify in a string of characters where an environment variable is used, and ultimately replace it with its actual value.

e.g. This is a very simple example of something much more complex.
**File "x.dat" contains:**

```
$MYDIR/file.txt
```

**Environment**

```
export MYDIR=/tmp/somefolder
```

**Script "x.sh"**

```
...
fileToProcess=$(cat x.dat)
realFileToProcess=$(eval echo $fileToProcess)
echo $realFileToProcess
...
```

Keep in mind that referenced environment variables in a string can also be:

```
${MYDIR}_txt
$MYDIR-txt
${MYDIR:0:3}:txt
${MYDIR:5}.txt
```

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167919/548225)

Answer (score 0):

Not an aswer yet but some remarks about the question.

It seems what you need is not variable expansion but token replacement in a template, depending the use case `printf` may be sufficient.

variable expansion depends also on context for example following are not replaced:

```
# single quotes
echo '${MYDIR}'

# ANSI-C quotes
echo $'${MYDIR}'

# heredoc with end marker enclosed between single quotes
cat << 'END'
${MYDIR}
END
```

Should be noted also that a variable expansion may execute arbitrary code:

```
echo ${X[`echo hi >&2`]}
```

Comment: The point is that I don't know that the x.dat contains ${MYDIR}, it could contain anything.