# How to read a file in shell, fill its variables from exports, and rewrite it to a new file?

Tags: shell

Let's say I have this file:

```
/temp/original_file.txt
```

The content of this file is:

```
Hello $FirstName, you have to accomplish $Task
```

I need to read this file, set variables dynamically, and write the result in a new file.
For example if `FirstName=Jack` and `Task=Cooking`, and the new file is located in `/temp/new_file.txt`, the content of the new file would be:

```
Hello Jack, you have to accomplish Cooking
```

How can I achieve this in shell?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030953/9072753 does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415677/how-to-replace-placeholders-in-a-text-file answer your question?

Comment: You find a proper templating tool.

Comment: @chepner, I only want to use shell.

Comment: @KamilCuk, it seems that `eval` might help. I'm testing those answers.

Comment: Eval is evil. Use `envsubst`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace ${} placeholders in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415677/how-to-replace-placeholders-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Yeah, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030953/16304630 helped me. But I had to change it a little bit. Basically it goes `envsubst < original_file_path > target_file_path`